# How do I set the default value of a protocol property in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols, default-value

I'e got this protocol.

```
//MyProtocolClass.h
@protocol MyProtocolDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
@property (nonatomic, assign) int anInteger;

@end

@interface MyProtocolClass:NSObject
@end
```

Then I'm using this protocol on this class:

```
//.h
@interface MyClass:NSObject <MyProtocolDelegate>
@end

//.m
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize anInteger;

    -(void) aFunction
    {
        NSLog(@"%d",self.anInteger);
        self.anInteger = 200;
        NSLog(@"%d",self.anInteger);
    }

@end
```

I want to set a default the value 100 on the variable `anInteger` so that it holds that value wether the user sets it or not.

The NSLogs should output:

```
100
200
```

I know how to do this using a function but can I do this using a property? 
Thank you.

Comment: you can only set `anInteger = 100` in a class method, a protocol cannot implement methods

Comment: So there can be no default value for such a property (right out of the box)..right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *property* is just a pair of methods, a getter and a setter. That's it. It says nothing about how the getter and setter may be implemented. There is no reason to assume that there is a backing "value" at all.

Answer (score 0):

set the property value,

```
-(void)setAnInteger:(int)anInteger
{
    self.anInteger = anInteger;
}
```

and call like this,

```
[self setAnInteger:100];
[self setAnInteger:200];
```

Comment: Where do I call this? I mean, I don't want to call this on MyClass.m, I'd prefer if the default value was given on  MyProtocolClass.m